# Privileges required to install PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am new to PostgreSQL Database. I need to install it in my machine.

I am not administrator in my system.

Can some one suggest, if  Non-Administrator can install it.

If there is any other way of installing apart from .exe, please let me know.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this [Starting PostgreSQL in windows without install.](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/172-Starting-PostgreSQL-in-windows-without-install.html)
Follow the steps below:

- Get binaries for Windows. You can either copy the postgresql folder
  (minus the data folder) from an existing PostgreSQL install, or just
  download the PostgreSQL binaries from PostgreSQL Windows. Make sure
  to choose the zip archive.
- Next copy the below batch file into the root of the postgresql folder
- For first time use, unremark out the (initdb step)
- Run the batch file:

.

```
@ECHO ON

REM The script sets environment variables helpful for PostgreSQL

@SET PATH="%~dp0\bin";%PATH%

@SET PGDATA=%~dp0\data

@SET PGDATABASE=postgres

@SET PGUSER=postgres

@SET PGPORT=5439

@SET PGLOCALEDIR=%~dp0\share\locale

REM "%~dp0\bin\initdb" -U postgres -A trust

"%~dp0\bin\pg_ctl" -D "%~dp0/data" -l logfile start

ECHO "Click enter to stop"

pause

"%~dp0\bin\pg_ctl" -D "%~dp0/data" stop
```